# Is the "secure-as-worst-case" version of NTRU patented?

Tags: ntru

Does the improved version of NTRU — which is described in ["Making NTRU as Secure as Worst-Case Problems over Ideal Lattices" by 
Stehlé and Steinfeld](http://users.monash.edu.au/~rste/ProvNTRU_V10a.pdf) — fall under the same patents as the original?

Comment: As a side-note: The proof is asymptotic and thus of limited value for practical key-sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for Security Innovation, which owns the NTRU patents. We think the NTRU patents would cover this algorithm too -- the patents are written broadly enough to cover different types of keys.

Note that although there are patents, we try to be reasonable about licensing terms. We have granted a free license for non-commercial use on many occasions and are currently exploring our options about licensing both the patents and a reference implementation under an open-source license. If you're interested in learning more, you can contact me directly on wwhyte@securityinnovation.com.

Comment: The patents are now available under GPL. Go use them!

Comment: Patents and copyright licenses are completely different things.

Comment: Yes, but the patent licenses are the important thing here because the spec is simple enough that you can implement it yourself, avoiding copyright issues.

BTW, all patents that may be necessary to implement the Stehle-Steinfeld approach have been released to the public domain, as has the source code: https://www.securityinnovation.com/company/news-and-events/press-releases/security-innovation-makes-ntruencrypt-patent-free